# Удаление при помощи бота сообщений с параметром via_bot в телеграм

Tags: python, telebot

Хочу добавить небольшие модераторские функции для своего бота в чат телеграм, чтобы он автоматически удалял сообщения от пользователей вот такого вида:
[image: сообщение, которое необходимо удалить]
Используется python и библиотека pyTelegramBotAPI. Как просто удалить сообщение с определенным текстом в сообщении или от определенного пользователя я понимаю, а вот какой метод применить с message, чтобы получить информацию о том, через какой бот это было отправлено (то есть должен быть какой-то параметр via_bot) и удалить именно это сообщение, не могу найти. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным.
P.S. словесные увещевания пользователей чата просто не использовать данного бота не сильно помогают... )

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено, можно использовать следующую конструкцию для удаления сообщений от конкретного бота, или же вообще от всех. Ниже код для удаления сообщений от конкретного. Напомню, у бота должен быть доступ к чтению и удалению сообщений в чате.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('*токен вашего бота*')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def delete_messages_via_bot(message):
if message.via_bot:
        if message.via_bot.username == '*название конкретного бота, которого хотите удалять*':
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```